# Find a set of nodes containing certainly at least one subset having a certain property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, where-clause, exists

Please I need Help for a Cypher that ensures resulting a set of nodes containing certainly at least one subset that verify a certain property value.

Each resulting set includes subsets.

The targeted set which I want as a result should have at least among the resulting subsets a subset that verify a property value.

Suppose I have :

R includes C includes S

That means

```
(c:C)-[:BELONGING_TO]->(r:R)-[r*0..1]-(s:S)
```

Suppose

```
    R={r1,r2,r3,...........rn} 
    C={c1,c2,c3,...........cn}
    S={sb1,sb2,sb3,...........sbn}

where sb1={s11,s12,s13.....s1n}
      sb2={s21,s22,s23.....s2n}
      sb3={s31,s32,s33.....s3n}
      .........................
      sbn={sn1,sn2,sn3.....snn}
```

## for example

```
MATCH (c:C)-[:BELONGING_TO]->(r:R)-[r*0..1]-(s:S) 
WHERE 
r.r='BLABLA' AND 
r.identifier='50' AND
c.identifier='504' 
return s.identifier as identifier
```

will return only a set of identifiers that includes only one subset  THAT VERIFY c.identifier='504'

AND I want to return a set that includes all subsets (i.e That verify r.r='BLABLA' AND r.identifier='50') AND Among those resulting subsets there is for sure at least and at most one subset that verify c.identifier='504'.

I want to get The set that includes for sure at least among the resulting subsets one subset that verify the propety value.

I tried **where EXISTS**  but unfortunately  I cant get what I want.

```
MATCH (c:C)-[:BELONGING_TO]->(r:R)-[r*0..1]-(s:S) 
WHERE EXISTS((s)-[*0..]-(c{identifier:'504'})) 
AND 
r.r='BLABLA' 
AND 
r.identifier='50'
```

N.B: The relationships between nodes are as below:

```
(s:S)-[rel1:IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_R*0..1]->(r:R)<-[rel2:IS_A_C_BELONGING_TO*0..1]-(c:C)<-[IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_THAT_C*0..1]-(s)
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR HELP.

## Update

suppose I have hierarchy1

```
R----
----C1
   ---------s1 have property c{identifier:'504'}
   ---------s2 have property c{identifier:'504'}
   ---------s3 have property c{identifier:'504'}
----C2
   ---------s21 have property c{identifier:'21'}
   ---------s22 have property c{identifier:'21'}
   ---------s23 have property c{identifier:'21'}
----C3
    ----------s31 have property c{identifier:'23'}
    ----------s32 have property c{identifier:'23'}
    ----------s33 have property c{identifier:'23'}
```

And another Hierarchy2 having the same names for R,C1,C2,C3

```
R----
----C1
   ---------s1 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
   ---------s2 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
   ---------s3 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
----C2
   ---------s21 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
   ---------s22 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
   ---------s23 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
----C3
    ----------s31 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
    ----------s32 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
    ----------s33 DON't have property c{identifier:'504'}**********
```

when i do my cypher I should get  all nodes s1,s2,s3,s21,s22,s23,s31,s32,s33 included in hierarchy1 and not from hierarchy2 because in hierarchy1 i have at least one subset nodes s1,s2,s3 having property c{identifier:'504'}
And in hierarchy 2 no one have c{identifier:'504'} so the second hierarchy will be ignored by my cypher.

The cypher will ensure that I got only the s included from hierarchy1
and no s from hierarchy2.

Because R,C1,C2,C3 names could be repeated in many hierarchies and I have a parameter c{identifier:XXXX} cypher that enbles to distinguish by them.

Comment: Still trying to understand what you're after here. Do you mean that you want `s` nodes (or their identifier) where only one of those `s` nodes is linked to the :C node with identifier '504', and the rest are not?

Comment: THANK YOU InverseFalcon . No those s nodes linked to the :C node with identifiers '504',  '708','908'.... etc but I'am certain that my cypher will ensure to result at least one  node with identifiers '504' from the resulting  subset of   s nodes linked to the :C node. .

Comment: identifiers '504' is passed as parameter to the cypher Request.

Comment: So the resulting `s` nodes will be linked to various `c` nodes. Given your `at least/ at most` description in your title, you seem to only want one of those `s` nodes to be linked with the `c` node with identifier 504, with no restrictions on the rest (just that they can't also be linked with `c` node 504). Is that correct? Or do you want to group the `s` nodes by their `c` node, so you'll have one list of `s` nodes linked with `c` node 504 and the rest linked with other c nodes?

Comment: The second option that means I want to group the s nodes by their c node, so I'll have one list of s nodes linked with c node 504 and the rest linked with other c nodes  but I a pretty sure to get at least at most one list of s nodes linked with c node 504.    I ll update my question to clarify that please see in bottom of the question.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, about how many :C nodes are there with identifier 504?

Comment: I update already my question hope you have seen that. we could have only one :C nodes with identifier 504. Thank you very much InverseFalcon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a handle on what you want.

The missing piece here is the grouping of `s` nodes by their `c` node. You'll want to use `collect()` here to gather your `s` nodes into lists, and by keeping the `c` node as a non-aggregation variable it will ensure that the `s` nodes are grouped for their relevant `c` node.

But first we have to deal with the filtering, to ensure we only choose :R nodes that have a match to :C nodes with identifier 504. It sounds like you have very few (or maybe only one?) :C node with identifier 504, so let's ensure we only choose :R nodes that are linked to the :C node in question, then continue on to :S nodes once we've filtered.

As a side note, you were using the `r` variable twice in your query, once for the :R node, and also for the optional relationship to the `s` node, so that won't work. We can remove the variable from the relationship.

```
MATCH (c:C)
WHERE c.identifier='504'
MATCH (r:R)
WHERE 
r.r='BLABLA' AND 
r.identifier='50' AND
(c)-[:BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH r
MATCH (c:C)-[:BELONGING_TO]->(r)-[*0..1]-(s:S)
WITH c, collect(DISTINCT s) as sList
RETURN c.identifier as cId, [s in sList | s.identifier] as sList
```

Comment: Thank you very much InverseFalcon. Tested and It works perfectly like a charm.